# Error after Server Upgrade - mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

I tried to search and found some similar questions but none seemed to help with my code.  I upgraded to a new server:

- MySQL = 5.0.96-community
- PHP = 4.4.9

I get following error:

> Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource in /path/to/file/filename.php on line 209

Here's the Line 209:

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

The code right above it for reference is:

```
<?

// Connect to DB

$db = mysql_connect("localhost","db_name","password");

if (!$db)
{
echo "No connection.";
exit;
}

mysql_select_db("db_name");

$v = str_replace(' ','_',$v);

$query = "SELECT * FROM reviews";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: You've upgraded to PHP/4.4.9 in 2014? What prior version were you using?

Comment: Did you check the mysql_error - `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: You _upgraded_ to PHP 4.4.9? You know that was released 3.5 years ago, and support was discontinued even before that?

Comment: @Clive - you mean they discontinued support even before releasing it?

Comment: @MarkBaker [Indeed](http://www.php.net/releases/) :)

Comment: @Clive - PHP/4.4.9 was [released in 2008](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-4.php#4.4.9).

Comment: PHP 4.4.9 Release date was 07-Aug-2008 - over 5 years ago

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Yep, and support for PHP 4 "has been discontinued since 2007-12-31". See the link...

Comment: @MarkBaker Sorry, you're right. 5.5 years. Support for PHP4 was discontinued in 2007 though, so still earlier

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing basic error checking:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
> resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or **FALSE on
> error**.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
> mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or **FALSE on error**

See also [mysql_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php):

> Returns the text of the error message from previous MySQL operation